# Pull files or folders uploaded by others in repository that I created

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Say I created a repository ABC and have shared it it with my colleagues. Then They uploaded files or created subfolders in this repository. What is the command like `hg pull` to retreive them to my local driver?

Comment: You should have a look at this Mercurial tutorial http://hginit.com/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ hg pull && hg update default` will work.